# Center a button or image

Tags: java, android, button, attributes

I'm using Eclipse to create an app for Android. I know you set attributes such as centering a button or image in the `XML` file but How would you do this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say without knowing what you have. However, if you look through the docs, every xml `attribute` has a related method in Java. For example, [Look at the View Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) and you can see a list of `attributes` with its corresponding Java method and a description of what it actually does. You should be able to use this to get you started then you can ask a question with code you have tried, precise problem you are having, and any error messages you might be getting. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use code to center your stuff, not attributes in an `XML` file.

**Center a button:**

Use a `FlowLayout`. This will keep the button centered horizontally in the container, but not vertically.

```
JButton button = new JButton("Click Me!");
panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
panel.add(button);
```

If you want it centered in both directions, you could use `BoxLayout`.

```
JButton button = new JButton("Click Me!");
button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
panel.add(button);
panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
```

**Center image:**

```
@Override 
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    int xCenter = (this.getWidth() - image.getWidth()) / 2;
    int yCenter = (this.getHeight() - image.getHeight()) / 2;
    g2d.drawImage(image, xCenter, yCenter, null); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
button.setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```